# flutter_hooks useState value is being reset to the initial value upon popping the stack

Tags: riverpod, flutter-hooks

I have this `useState`:

```
class RegisterFormPageWidget extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const RegisterFormPageWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final vm = ref.watch<RegisterPageVm>(registerPageVm);
    vm.page = useState(0);
```

But every time I navigate away with `Navigator.of(context).pop()`, `vm.page.value` becomes `0` again.

I've put a print statement in the constructor to ensure it is not recreated:

```
class RegisterPageVm {
  RegisterPageVm({required this.entity}) {
    print('new instance');
  }
```

I can confirm it is only every constructed once. I have looked for all instances of `vm.page.value = 0` and there is never code running that does that.

Any ideas what else I can check to figure out why `vm.page.value` is getting reset to `0` upon popping the stack?

Answer (score 1):

I ***think*** this is the cause:

`vm.page = useState(0);` resets to `0` after a  `Navigator.pop` then navigating back to the page because `useState` is in the page that gets destroyed by the `pop`. So even though the vm does not get destroyed, the page that got destroyed is setting the `vm.page`.

In which case `useState` is not suitable because it is state that lives only as long as the widget that it is in.

I have confirmed this flow, where the widget reconstructs after Navigator.pop, and navigating back to it. It would be good to know if there is some way to make `hook`s live longer than the widgets they are in. I doubt there is. For now, I have migrated to a Riverpod `StateNotifier`.